# URL specific encode

Tags: php

I try to recreate a URL but can not find the encoding function

**Edit:**
background:
the string is for an API (with no documentation ofcourse), I tried to use **rawurlencode** but it seems that only the original  encode / decode functions work so I have to find what it is ...

```
$input = "2/3*( ((word*888) )>(word2 AND ((word3*888))/word4>888";

$encoded = "2/3*(%20((word*888)%20)%3E(word2%20AND%20((word3*888))/word4%3E2888";
```

Tried with **urlendode**, **rawurlencode** but they replace  the brackets and "*"..

The string is created for URL from  PHP (possibly Javascript).

**Edit**
**base64_encode** - destroys the string ..
**htmlentities** - is not making changes ..

Not looking for "best url encode function" .. just need to recreate the example without custom replace function.

**Edit3**
OK I did some more debugging and this is the most of the replace table:

% - %25
^ - %5E
+ - %2B
{ - %7B
[ - %5B
} - %7D
] - %5D
" - %22
| - %7C
\ - %5C
< - %3C
`>` - %3E
" " - %20

May be some sort of  escape for SQL, the string is later transformed to a query.

Comment: Is that an SQL `WHERE` clause?

Comment: You can always use `base64_encode`.

Comment: i am smelling huge trouble down this path

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ab7-ruz check this it works

Comment: I think you may have your own reasons to keep the slash, brackets and asterisk. Thus you may just need a function to make use of a group of str_replace. For example, to replace space with %20, and > with %3E.

Comment: Is this homework by any chance?

Comment: @geomagas No, reverse engineering a legacy API.

Comment: @d.raev Sorry, but I was confused by _"just need to recreate the example without custom replace function"_. Seemed like an exercise requirement to me.

Comment: Why not use urlencode() ?

Comment: urlencode was what I originally tried, but it replaces some character (brackets, *, etc) and the API does not respond as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a PHP implementation of JavaScript [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) function. Here we go:

```
function encodeURI($uri)
{
    return preg_replace_callback("{[^0-9a-z_.!~*'();,/?:@&=+$#]}i", function ($m) {
            return sprintf('%%%02X', ord($m[0]));
        }, $uri);
}
```

And now you have exactly what you want.

Demo: https://eval.in/65314

Comment: good catch with js:encodeURL() seems as the original function. I found that the problem was in fact in another part of the URL ... but will accept your answer as it is good answer for the OP.

Comment: @d.raev Thank you! Hope it can be helpful for everyone! :)